# SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B

Tags: python, funciones, variables, matemáticas, print

> Mi codigo:

```
def crearFila (ancho):
    return "*" * ancho

def crearRectangulo (ancho, alto):
    fila = crearFila (ancho)
    area = (fila+"\n")*alto

    return area

def main():
    ancho = int(input("Ingrese ancho: "))
    alto = int(input("Ingrese alto: "))
    print(crearRectangulo​​(ancho, alto))

main ()
```

> El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
%Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14
    print(crearRectangulo​​(ancho, alto))
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B
```

> Pareciera que es algo de que no puede hacer `print` a ese valor. De todas maneras no se como resolverlo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Tienes un par de caracteres `ZWSP` (Espacio en blanco con ancho cero) entre `crearRectangulo` y el paréntesis, solo los pude ver al pegarlos en un editor de texto que muestre todos los caracteres como Notepad++. Es posible que los hayas escrito por accidente o algún compañero de clase te hizo una "broma". Borra esos dos caracteres y listo.

Comment: Aaahhh, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Como dice el comentario de: "HeytalePazguato", deberias borrar esos dos caracteres. Antes de ver que ya habian respondido estaba pensando en decir que borraras la linea entera y la volvieras a escribir. (Creo que fue un gran aporte a "Pedro" el comentario de "HeytalePazguato").

Answer (score 1):

Primero observe que al ejecutar el programa sí sale un resultado sin la función que marca el error. Hasta ahí puede estar seguro que su programa funciona.
[image: run_first_time]

Yo le propongo separa un poco más su código para que tome la siguiente forma

```py
def crearFila (ancho):
    return "*" * ancho

def area(ancho, alto):
    return ancho*alto

def crearRectangulo (ancho, alto):
    for _ in range(alto):
      print(crearFila(ancho))
    return area(ancho, alto)

def main():
    ancho = int(input("Ingrese ancho: "))
    alto = int(input("Ingrese alto: "))
    area = crearRectangulo(ancho, alto)
    print(area)

main()

Ingrese ancho: 10
Ingrese alto: 10
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
100
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.